# Create an excel graph on excel sheet with python

Tags: python, excel, graphics

I am trying to create an excel chart using python.
I know that it is possible to write functions on a cell. I have also implemented a matplotlib chart but this is not what my employer wants.
He wants to be able to manipulate the graph when he opens the excel sheet but I can't find a function that can select the data and create a plot(x,y).

Thanks for your help!

```
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    sht = wb['fig']
    sht['C3']=wb['main'].Range("A1:B2000")
```